# PyQt5: QSqlTableModel connecting with QTableView and QLineEdit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qt5, pyqt5

So I got the project I am building, I have QDialog with a QTableView, QPushButton and a QLineEdit.

I made the model that Data from the database, i created the mapper to set the data from the DB to my LineEdit and gave the model to the QTableView.
so I have tried and tried with no success to connect the Table to LineEdits.

To do something like these "When I click the row it fills the LineEdit with the data that on that row, and saves the data when edit"
here what I got until now:

```
from ui_categorias import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt5.Qt import QMessageBox, QDialog, QDataWidgetMapper
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlRelationalTableModel, QSqlTableModel

class frmCategories(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, dbCon=None, strTblName=None):
        super(frmCategories, self).__init__(parent=None)
        self.setupUi(self)

        #Criando o Model
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self,dbCon)
        self.model.setTable(strTblName)
        self.model.select()

        a = self.model
        self.mapFields()

    def mapFields(self):
        id, nome, descricao, comentarios,activo = range(0,5)
        '''
        Esta funcao estabekece as ligacoes entre os widgets e o modelo

        '''
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.LECodigo, id)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.LENome, nome)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.PTEDescricao, descricao)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.PTEComentarios, comentarios)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.CBActivo, activo)
        self.mapper.toFirst()

        self.TVCategorias.setModel(self.model)
```

The ui_file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '/Users/chernomirdinmacuvele/Documents/workspace/PescArt2.0/UserInt/ui_categorias.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.8.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(407, 486)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(7, 68, 77, 51))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.PTEComentarios = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.PTEComentarios.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 128, 301, 71))
        self.PTEComentarios.setObjectName("PTEComentarios")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(7, 128, 91, 71))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.TVCategorias = QtWidgets.QTableView(Dialog)
        self.TVCategorias.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(7, 232, 391, 211))
        self.TVCategorias.setObjectName("TVCategorias")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(7, 39, 77, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.CBActivo = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Dialog)
        self.CBActivo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(93, 208, 81, 20))
        self.CBActivo.setObjectName("CBActivo")
        self.LECodigo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.LECodigo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 8, 301, 21))
        self.LECodigo.setObjectName("LECodigo")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(7, 8, 77, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.LENome = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.LENome.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 39, 301, 21))
        self.LENome.setObjectName("LENome")
        self.PTEDescricao = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(Dialog)
        self.PTEDescricao.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 70, 301, 51))
        self.PTEDescricao.setObjectName("PTEDescricao")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 449, 391, 32))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.PEEditar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.PEEditar.setObjectName("PEEditar")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.PEEditar)
        self.PBGuardar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.PBGuardar.setObjectName("PBGuardar")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.PBGuardar)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Recursos Pesqueiros"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Descricao:"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Comentarios:"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Nome:"))
        self.CBActivo.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Activo"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Codigo:"))
        self.PEEditar.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Editar"))
        self.PBGuardar.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Guardar"))
```

Comment: Please show the Ui_Dialog code.

Comment: When you ask a question you must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: there you go the ui_file just edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

founded a possible solution.

```
 def getInfTbl(self, row = QModelIndex): #only call parameters of that kind
    curWorkmodel = self.TVCategorias.model() #Get The current working model  
    clickedRow = row.row() # index from the item the mouse clicked #QModelIndex 
    self.mapper.setCurrentModelIndex(row) # set index of the mapper to the same as in the model
    for i in range(0,5): #1-Codigo 2-Nome 3-Descrica 4-Comentario 5-Inativo
        curWorkmodel.index(clickedRow,i) #the index the item  correspond to
```